# Any linux working in Acer Aspire 7 (R5 5500U + GTX 1650)?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, debian-installer

I have tried installing many linux but none works, most don't get past grub, some doesn't even get installed. Some stuck on black screen with blinking cursor after grub.

If anyone knows a fix or has tried installing then please do tell.

Distros I tried with -

1. Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa - gets installed after doing grub edit `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`. After install booting too also requires to do so from elevated terminal.
   When it boots up, says `not using GPU hardware, CPU usage would be more`. When I update Nvidia GPU driver and restarts it gets stuck at black screen with blinking cursor after grub and I can't even open terminal from there, it just shows for a while then disappears again and cursor blinking comes again. Tried updating driver by downloading from Nvidia site. Tried running the .run file but it said same X server is running.
2. Ubuntu 20.4 LTS - installs fine, boots up after making the required grub edit. But doesn't shutdown, suspend or log out and hangs a lot.
3. Debian netinst/live/live-non free firmware - doesn't even get past grub menu, stuck on cursor blink screen even after grub edit.
4. openSUSE - says couldn't open graphic install. reason memory less than 94MB or X server could not be started/stopped (don't remember exactly). If I proceed then fail at firs step only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please ask here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov ok will post

Comment: This is for a 5 which should be similar: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pop os or use grauda linux those worked fine with my acer aspire 7 ( ryzen 5 5500U / Gtx 1650)